# Flyway Mysql multiline comment directive not parsed

Tags: flyway

I am wondering if there is any news for multi line comment directive support for MySql.

I believe the problem is related to:

[Mysql dump comments directives and simple comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036990/mysql-dump-comments-directives-and-simple-comments)

Basically it seems SqlScript/MySQLSqlStatementBuilder fail in recognizing as directive a statement in the format:

```
/*!50001 <STATEMENT SPLITTED IN 
MULTI
LINES> */;
```

I am using version 2.2.1

Additional notes:

the same goes for previous versions (2.1.1), and issues are multiple and not only related to comment directives; theu are also hard to debug because of missing exception trace.

Basically I think parser cannot currently handle pretty standard mysql scripts created with mysqldump; this IMO is a necessary feature for any usage in existing projects at least.

If anybody has suggestions to overcome these issues, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Flyway 2.1.1 API in Java.

What I am doing is parsing a dump file (only the schema structure) and replace the version dependant comments.

This solution is pretty bad, but waiting for a better support of MySQL dump in Flyway, I didn't find anything else...